# render a container inside another VUEjs

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuex

I have two composites, a father and a son who is also recursive.
the data filling template is loaded from an api

the problem that, when opening some child, all the children are opened, and the content of all the grandchildren is repeated in all the children

I'm trying to create a tree, where each child calls their children and so on, these calls are Fetch requests,

I'm stuck here, and I don't understand very well how VUE works in these cases, so my question, thank you.

something like this https://codepen.io/anthonygore/pen/PJKNqa?editors=1010, but each item is a call to an api

[image of the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqivZ.png)

```js
import * from '....';

export default {
    name: 'cList',
    components : {
        itett,
    },
    props : ['id', 'entity', 'treeData'],
    data  : ()=>{return{
        loading: true,
        tree: {},
        child_component: false,
        tdata: false,
    }},
    methods: {
        clop: function(state, uid, ev){
            let _childs = document.querySelector(`[data-idml="${uid}"]`);
            if( _childs ) {
                switch (state) {
                    case 'close': _childs.classList.add('hide'); break;
                    case 'open' : _childs.classList.remove('hide'); this.getChildren(uid); break;
                }
            }
        },
        getChildren: function( uid ){
            this.child_component = false;
            let _tdata = {};
            let de   = uid.split('_');
            let _elm = Entity.create({ is: de[0], id: de[1] });
            let tot  = _elm.childs.length - 1, cnt = 0;

            _elm.childs.forEach((et, ix) => {
                if( _elm.type && _elm.id ) {
                    ApiEntity.getList({
                        entity: et,
                        parents: [+_elm.id],
                        parentType: _elm.type,
                        cascade: false,
                    }).then(res => {
                        if( Array.isArray(res) ) {
                            _tdata[et] = res;
                        }
                        if( cnt >= tot ) {
                            this.tdata = _tdata;
                            this.child_component = 'cList';
                        }
                        cnt++;
                    }).catch( err => { console.error( err ); });
                }
            });
        },

        seeMore: function(uid){ }

    },
    beforeMount: function(){
        this.tree = {};
        if( this.entity ) {
            Entity.fetch(this.entity)
            .then(res => {
                this.tree[this.entity] = res;
                this.loading = false;
            }).catch( err => { console.error( err ); });

        } else if( this.treeData ) {
            this.tree = this.treeData;
            this.loading = false;
        }
    },

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div class="ch_list">
      <template v-if="loading"> Loading.... </template>
      <template v-else>
      <ul class="lsitm" v-for="(value, name, ig) in tree" :key="ig">
          <li v-for="(elm) in value" :key="elm.uid">
              <itett class="ls_line" :data="elm" @clop="clop"></itett>
              <div class="ls_childs hide" :data-idml="elm.uid">
                  <div class="ch_header"></div>
                  <!-- <keep-alive> -->
                      <component v-bind:is="child_component" :treeData="tdata"></component>
                  <!-- </keep-alive> -->
                  <div class="ch_more"> <button @click="seeMore(`${entity}_${id}`, $event)">see mas</button> </div>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </template>
   </div>
</template>
```